# clock operating switch

Tags: switches, integrated-circuit, clock

I have 2 channels that I want to switch between every 15 sec.
so I guess I need a switch that switches channels by logical pulse ( lm555 I guess?)
which ic/ circuit would be the best?
Accuracy of the switch doesn't matter much ( 1/2 sec delay wont hurt anyone)
the channels will have up to 200ma of current  - 9V of voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and easiest solution for you would be to use regular relays,  the electromechanical kind. They are slow, but certainly fast enough for what you need. 200mA could be high for IC kind of signal-agnostic switches which are easily available. Most relays can handle that current without breaking a sweat.

You would use a clock generator of some sort to create a signal that toggles every 15 seconds. This signal can be fed into the gate of a transistor to turn on one of two simple SPST relays or flip the direction of a SPDT/DPDT relay. In case of using two relays,  you would use a not gate (or reverse the relay coil drive cricuit) for the second relay, to make them react in opposite ways to the original signal.

The problem you will face, though, is that 15 seconds is a long time. I'm not sure if a 555 and similar will be able to generate such low frequencies. You have two options.  One would be the expensive route of generating the 1/15 Hz square wave in the firmware of some microcontroller. The other, and cleaner solution,  would be to use the 555 at a low frequency which it does support. It should be able to go down to 10 Hz atleast, i think,  but you should check the datasheet. You can then reduce the frequency using a frequency divider circuit, which can easily be made using a binary counter (or multiple binary counters cascaded for greater dactors of division)

Comment: 555 can handle those times easily with common components. Just a few weeks ago made my kitty a toy using a motor with string attached that's on a few seconds every two minutes and from memory only needed a 100uF cap and a few resistors in the few 100's of K range.

Comment: about the clock, I know what do to, but I never used a relay before,  how expensive is a regular SPDT relay?

Comment: Cheap. In India, I get them for about 0.5 USD when I buy one of them. You'd also need a transistor, a resistor, and a diode at least for each relay, maybe a few more similar passives for protection.

Answer (score 1):

For the switching pulse, there are plenty of options, the 555 is one of them.

A simple [astable circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator) with two relays might be a very simple option:

[image: Astable Switcher]

Simulation:

[image: Astable Switcher Simulation]

The NPN and N-ch MOSFET shown can be replaced with almost any similar parts. It won't be very accurate timing wise due to the electrolytic capacitors tolerances, but you said that wasn't a requirement. R3 and R4 can be replaced with potentiometers wired as rheostats (or small pot added in series with R3/4 for easier tuning) so you can fine tune the timing and compensate for the capacitors if necessary.
The actual switches are not shown, just the relay coils - the switches can both be connected to the signal as necessary, when one switch is on, the other is off.

**555/Microcontroller/etc**

There are numerous timing ICs available which can be used here (the 555 being most popular), a search on Digikey, Farnell, etc will find them.
If you are familiar with microcontrollers, then this is obviously an easy task for a micro, and with a crystal/resonator can be very accurate.
Any of the above with a suitable switch or two can be used, SPDT (latching is nice for reduced power consumption) relay is a one part solution (which can be used with a few changes to the above circuit) There are various solid state relays SSRs and multiplexers which can be used also.
A couple of, or single SPDT [OptoMOS IC](http://www.clare.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/Lcc120.pdf/$file/Lcc120.pdf) (example linked only handles up 170mA) is yet another option if you want the signal to be isolated.